# Most efficent way to do where search with unknown amount of variables to match with EF linq?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, lambda

I'm using entity framework and am making a method that can take in up to three variables

```
public SearchTable(int var1, int var2, int var3)
```

I want to be able to do a where with entity framework, but only on the variables passed in.

So if all three were passed in, it would be something like this:

```
var results = entities.vw_ToSearch.Where(x => x.var1 == var1 && x.var2 == var2 && x.var3 == var3);
```

but if for example var2 is passed in as null and no value, i want it to only do the where on var1 and var2.

I started writing this out making a different where statement for each possibility and was going to do a bunch of if statements to check which one to use, but it seems like there would be a better way to do this that i am not thinking of.

Any thoughts?

Comment: This is unclear. First, if var2 is null then how this relates to searching with `var1` and `var2`? Then, you pass VALUES to the method and then suddenly you use these values as column references (`var1` vs `x.var1`).

Answer (score 1):

Since you are ANDing the predicates, you could apply the following logic:

```
IQueryable<vw_ToSearchItem> results = entities.vw_ToSearch;
if (x.var1.HasValue)
   results = results.Where(x => x.var1 == var1);
if (x.var2.HasValue)
   results = results.Where(x => x.var2 == var2);
if (x.var3.HasValue)
   results = results.Where(x => x.var3 == var3);
```

The advantage of this approach is that you only pass the filters that you need to your database and don't require it to do the nullability check on each row (possibly resulting in a table scan rather than leveraging established indexes). As with most any performance question, you need to evaluate the generated execution plans of each approach to see which is best for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

One option may be to use [Dynamic LINQ](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
Where( x => x.var1==var1 &&
    (var2 == null || x.var2 == var2))
```

Add "ad libitum" for more than 2...